# Extracting data from script tag using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, deezer

I want to extract "SNG_TITLE" and "ART_NAME" values from the code in "script" tag using BeautifulSoup in Python. (the whole script is too long to paste)

```
<script>window.__DZR_APP_STATE__ = {"TAB":{"loved":{"data":[{"SNG_ID":"126884459","PRODUCT_TRACK_ID":"360276641","UPLOAD_ID":0,"SNG_TITLE":"Heathens","ART_ID":"647650","PROVIDER_ID":"3","ART_NAME":"Twenty One Pilots","ARTISTS":[{"ART_ID":"647650","ROLE_ID":"0","ARTISTS_SONGS_ORDER":"1","ART_NAME":"Twenty One Pilots","ART_PICTURE":"259dcf52853363d79753ec301377645d","SMARTRADIO":"1","RANK":"487762","LOCALES":[],"__TYPE__":"artist"}],"ALB_ID":"13371165","ALB_TITLE":"Heathens","TYPE":0,"MD5_ORIGIN":"5cea723b83af1ff0a62d65d334b978d4","VIDEO":false,"DURATION":"195","ALB_PICTURE":"3dfc8c9e406cf1bba8ce0695a44a9b7e","ART_PICTURE":"259dcf52853363d79753ec301377645d","RANK_SNG":"967143","SMARTRADIO":"1","FILESIZE_AAC_64":0,"FILESIZE_MP3_64":"0","FILESIZE_MP3_128":"3135946","FILESIZE_MP3_256":0,"FILESIZE_MP3_320":"7839868","FILESIZE_FLAC":"21777150","FILESIZE":"3135946","GAIN":"-12","MEDIA_VERSION":"4","DISK_NUMBER":"1","TRACK_NUMBER":"1","VERSION":"","EXPLICIT_LYRICS":"0","RIGHTS":{"STREAM_ADS_AVAILABLE":true,"STREAM_ADS":"2000-01-01","STREAM_SUB_AVAILABLE":true,"STREAM_SUB":"2000-01-01"},"ISRC":"USAT21601930","DATE_ADD":1497886149,"HIERARCHICAL_TITLE":"","SNG_CONTRIBUTORS":{"mainartist":["Twenty One Pilots"],"engineer":["Adam Hawkins"],"mixer":["Adam Hawkins"],"masterer":["Chris Gehringer"],"drums":["Josh Dun"],"producer":["Mike Elizondo","Tyler Joseph"],"programmer":["Mike Elizondo","Tyler Joseph"],"vocals":["Tyler Joseph"],"writer":["Tyler Joseph"]},"LYRICS_ID":30553991,"__TYPE__":"song"},{"SNG_ID":"99976952","PRODUCT_TRACK_ID":"171067651","UPLOAD_ID":0,"SNG_TITLE":"Stressed Out","ART_ID":"647650","PROVIDER_ID":"3","ART_NAME":"Twenty One Pilots","ARTISTS":[{"ART_ID":"647650","ROLE_ID":"0","ARTISTS_SONGS_ORDER":"1","ART_NAME":"Twenty One Pilots", ...</script>
```

The idea of the code is to print out the user name, all song and artist names that can be found on the given page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.deezer.com/en/profile/1589856782/loved'

r = requests.get(base_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

user_name = soup.find(class_='user-name')
print(user_name.text)
```

This prints the user name.

```
for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    print(script.contents)
```

If I understand correctly, the script I need is a dictionary, so I just need to find it and get its contents. The problem is I don't know how to specifically find **exactly this** "script". It doesn't have any attributes or anything that makes it unique. So I tried a loop that finds all scripts on the page and prints out their contents, but not sure how to proceed further.

How do I find only this particular "script" on the page? Can I access the values in a different way?

Comment: Is that you want to extract the script element with "window.__DZR_APP_STATE__ " in it?

Comment: count scripts in code - they don't change places - and use index to get correct one - ie. third script `soup.find_all('script')[2]`

Comment: BTW: script is normal string so you can use standard string functions to check it - ie `if "loved" in script.contents:`

Answer (score 6):

Scripts don't change places in code so you can count them and use index to get correct script.

```
all_scripts[6]
```

Script is normal string so you can also use standard string functions ie.

```
if '{"loved"' in script.text:
```

Code with both methods - I use `[:100]` to display only part of string.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.deezer.com/en/profile/1589856782/loved'

r = requests.get(base_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')

print('--- first method ---')
print(all_scripts[6].text[:100])

print('--- second method ---')
for number, script in enumerate(all_scripts):
    if '{"loved"' in script.text:
        print(number, script.text[:100])
```

Result:

```
--- first method ---
window.__DZR_APP_STATE__ = {"TAB":{"loved":{"data":[{"SNG_ID":"126884459","PRODUCT_TRACK_ID":"360276
--- second method ---
6 window.__DZR_APP_STATE__ = {"TAB":{"loved":{"data":[{"SNG_ID":"126884459","PRODUCT_TRACK_ID":"360276
```

---

**EDIT:** When you have correct script then you can use slicing to get only `JSON` string and use module `json` to convert it to python dictionary and then tou can get data

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

base_url = 'https://www.deezer.com/en/profile/1589856782/loved'

r = requests.get(base_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')

data = json.loads(all_scripts[6].get_text()[27:])

print('key:', data.keys())
print('key:', data['TAB'].keys())
print('key:', data['DATA'].keys())
print('---')

for item in data['TAB']['loved']['data']:
    print('ART_NAME:', item['ART_NAME'])
    print('SNG_TITLE:', item['SNG_TITLE'])
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
key: dict_keys(['TAB', 'DATA'])
key: dict_keys(['loved'])
key: dict_keys(['USER', 'FOLLOW', 'FOLLOWING', 'HAS_BLOCKED', 'IS_BLOCKED', 'IS_PUBLIC', 'CURATOR', 'IS_PERSONNAL', 'NB_FOLLOWER', 'NB_FOLLOWING'])
---
ART_NAME: Twenty One Pilots
SNG_TITLE: Heathens
---
ART_NAME: Twenty One Pilots
SNG_TITLE: Stressed Out
---
ART_NAME: Linkin Park
SNG_TITLE: Numb
---
ART_NAME: Three Days Grace
SNG_TITLE: Animal I Have Become
---
ART_NAME: Three Days Grace
SNG_TITLE: Painkiller
---
ART_NAME: Slipknot
SNG_TITLE: Before I Forget
---
ART_NAME: Slipknot
SNG_TITLE: Duality
---
ART_NAME: Skrillex
SNG_TITLE: Make It Bun Dem
---
ART_NAME: Skrillex
SNG_TITLE: Bangarang (feat. Sirah)
---
ART_NAME: Limp Bizkit
SNG_TITLE: Break Stuff
---
ART_NAME: Three Days Grace
SNG_TITLE: I Hate Everything About You
---
ART_NAME: Three Days Grace
SNG_TITLE: Time of Dying
---
ART_NAME: Three Days Grace
SNG_TITLE: I Am Machine
---
ART_NAME: Three Days Grace
SNG_TITLE: Riot
---
ART_NAME: Three Days Grace
SNG_TITLE: So What
---
ART_NAME: Three Days Grace
SNG_TITLE: Pain
---
ART_NAME: Three Days Grace
SNG_TITLE: Tell Me Why
---
ART_NAME: Three Days Grace
SNG_TITLE: Chalk Outline
---
ART_NAME: Three Days Grace
SNG_TITLE: Gone Forever
---
ART_NAME: Slipknot
SNG_TITLE: The Devil In I
---
ART_NAME: Linkin Park
SNG_TITLE: No More Sorrow
---
ART_NAME: Linkin Park
SNG_TITLE: Bleed It Out
---
ART_NAME: The Doors
SNG_TITLE: Roadhouse Blues
---
ART_NAME: The Doors
SNG_TITLE: Riders On The Storm
---
ART_NAME: The Doors
SNG_TITLE: Break On Through (To The Other Side)
---
ART_NAME: The Doors
SNG_TITLE: Alabama Song (Whisky Bar)
---
ART_NAME: The Doors
SNG_TITLE: People Are Strange
---
ART_NAME: My Chemical Romance
SNG_TITLE: Welcome to the Black Parade
---
ART_NAME: My Chemical Romance
SNG_TITLE: Teenagers
---
ART_NAME: My Chemical Romance
SNG_TITLE: Na Na Na [Na Na Na Na Na Na Na Na Na]
---
ART_NAME: My Chemical Romance
SNG_TITLE: Famous Last Words
---
ART_NAME: The Doors
SNG_TITLE: Soul Kitchen
---
ART_NAME: The Black Keys
SNG_TITLE: Lonely Boy
---
ART_NAME: Katy Perry
SNG_TITLE: I Kissed a Girl
---
ART_NAME: Katy Perry
SNG_TITLE: Hot N Cold
---
ART_NAME: Katy Perry
SNG_TITLE: E.T.
---
ART_NAME: Linkin Park
SNG_TITLE: Given Up
---
ART_NAME: My Chemical Romance
SNG_TITLE: Dead!
---
ART_NAME: My Chemical Romance
SNG_TITLE: Mama
---
ART_NAME: My Chemical Romance
SNG_TITLE: The Sharpest Lives
---
```

Answer (score 3):

If my understanding is correct, you want only the script element with "SNG_TITLE" in it.

You can use `re` and get only the script element with the fields of your interest as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

base_url = 'https://www.deezer.com/en/profile/1589856782/loved'

r = requests.get(base_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

user_name = soup.find(class_='user-name')
print(user_name.text)

for script in soup(text=re.compile(r'SNG_TITLE' )):
    print(script.parent)
```

**EDIT:**

@furas answer is the complete solution using `json` to find the 'SNG_TITLE' and 'ART_TITLE'. My answer help you find only the script with 'SNG_TITLE'. You can combine both to get better code.