# Downloading *.mp4 files form url with Python

Tags: python-3.x, video, python-requests, html5-video, mp4

Im triying to generate an array of [url_audioenci,url_caratula,titulo_cancion,nombre_artista] to download a list of music from http://los40.com.ar/lista40/. I know how to download media with Requests library, but i cant extract and the links from the page

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
# import re
url = 'http://los40.com.ar/m/lista40/'
videos = []
response = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
for i in range (1,41):
    videos[i]= bs.find_all('datos_camcion_'+i))
# responses= bs.find_all('script', language="javascript", type="text/javascript")

print(videos)
```

```html
<h3>LISTA DEL 08/06/2019</h3>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var datos_cancion_1 = Array();
  datos_cancion_1['url_audioenci']         = 'https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/audios/dest/570005645440.mp4';
  datos_cancion_1['url_muzu']         = '';
  datos_cancion_1['url_youtube']      = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsX3ATc3FbA';
  datos_cancion_1['url_itunes']       = '';
  datos_cancion_1['posicion']         = '1';
  datos_cancion_1['url_caratula']     = 'https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/fotos/dest/570005645461.jpg';
  datos_cancion_1['titulo_cancion']   = 'Boy with luv';
  datos_cancion_1['nombre_artista']   = 'BTS;Halsey';
  datos_cancion_1['idYes']            = 'BTS';
  datos_cancion_1['VidAu']            = 0;
</script>
```

I expect

```
videos=[['https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/audios/dest/570005645440.mp4','https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/fotos/dest/570005645461.jpg','Boy with luv','BTS;Halsey'].....]
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at filtering the data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://los40.com.ar/m/lista40/'
videos = []
response = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="html5lib")

scripts = bs.find_all('script', language='javascript', type='text/javascript') 
end = len( bs.find_all('script', language='javascript', type='text/javascript') )
start = end - 40
data = []

for i in range( start, end ):
    data.append( str(scripts[ i ]) )

print( data[0] )
```

Output:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var datos_cancion_1 = Array();
  datos_cancion_1['url_audioenci']         = 'https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/audios/dest/570005645440.mp4';
  datos_cancion_1['url_muzu']         = '';
  datos_cancion_1['url_youtube']      = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsX3ATc3FbA';
  datos_cancion_1['url_itunes']       = '';
  datos_cancion_1['posicion']         = '1';
  datos_cancion_1['url_caratula']     = 'https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/fotos/dest/570005645461.jpg';
  datos_cancion_1['titulo_cancion']   = 'Boy with luv';
  datos_cancion_1['nombre_artista']   = 'BTS;Halsey';
  datos_cancion_1['idYes']            = 'BTS';
  datos_cancion_1['VidAu']            = 0;
</script>
```

Data[0:39] contains the top 40 and all the relevant data as strings, but I'm not sure how to extract the information *from* the strings.

There are some suggestions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030726/extracting-data-from-script-tag-using-beautifulsoup-in-python) via `import json` or `import re` that I tried fiddling with, but I couldn't get them to work.