# How to extract content from <script> using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to extract campaign_hearts and postal_code from the code in the script tag here (the entire code is too long to post):

```
<script>
...    
"campaign_hearts":4817,"social_share_total":11242,"social_share_last_update":"2020-01-17T10:51:22-06:00","location":{"city":"Los Angeles, CA","country":"US","postal_code":"90012"},"is_partner":false,"partner":{},"is_team":true,"team":{"name":"Team STEVENS NATION","team_pic_url":"https://d2g8igdw686xgo.cloudfront.net
...
```

I can identify the script I need with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
import requests 
import re
import json


page = requests.get("https://www.gofundme.com/f/eric-stevens-care-trust")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
all_scripts[0]
```

However, I'm at a loss for how to extract the values I want. (I'm very new to Python.) 
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030726/extracting-data-from-script-tag-using-beautifulsoup-in-python) recommended the following solution for a similar problem (edited to reflect the html I'm working with).

```
data = json.loads(all_scripts[0].get_text()[27:])
```

However, running this produces an error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).`

What can I do to extract the values I need now that I have the correct script identified? I have also tried the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111752/extracting-text-from-script-tag-using-beautifulsoup-in-python), but had trouble importing Parser.

Answer (score 4):

You can parse the content of `<script>` with `json` module and then get your values. For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.gofundme.com/f/eric-stevens-care-trust'

txt = requests.get(url).text

data = json.loads(re.findall(r'window\.initialState = ({.*?});', txt)[0])

# print( json.dumps(data, indent=4) )  # <-- uncomment this to see all data

print('Campaign Hearts =', data['feed']['campaign']['campaign_hearts'])
print('Postal Code     =', data['feed']['campaign']['location']['postal_code'])
```

Prints:

```
Campaign Hearts = 4817
Postal Code     = 90012
```

Comment: Never knew this way of loading JSON. Awesome! :)

Comment: Isn't `re.findall()[0]` just `re.search()`?

Comment: @AMC It could be written as `re.search(r'window\.initialState = ({.*?});', txt).group(1)` or `re.search(..)[1]`. It's just matter of taste.

Comment: _It's just matter of taste._ Only somewhat, since `.findall()` will get every single match, regardless of whether or not it's thrown away later.

Answer (score 2):

The more libraries you use; the more inefficient a code becomes! Here is a simpler solution-

```
#This imports the website content.

import requests
url = "https://www.gofundme.com/f/eric-stevens-care-trust"
a = requests.post(url)
a= (a.content)
print(a)

#These will show your data.

campaign_hearts = str(a,'utf-8').split('campaign_hearts":')[1]
campaign_hearts = campaign_hearts.split(',"social_share_total"')[0]
print(campaign_hearts)

postal_code = str(a,'utf-8').split('postal_code":"')[1]
postal_code = postal_code.split('"},"is_partner')[0]
print(postal_code)
```

Comment: Just to add : I wouldn't say the code becomes less "efficient" because it is often implied *speed* efficiency when talking about efficiency, which is not the case here. But it would become less *straightforward*, as it adds the need to understand more different libraries.

Comment: Yes. I was just meaning that you don't need the entire infinity gauntlet when the work can just be done with time stone haha :)

Comment: That remains true indeed :)

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using a POST request?

Comment: Speaking of efficiency, what happens if OP wants the entire JSON content?

Comment: I wrote POST on the moment of the spur. Nothing significant. The answer is just addressing the exact question. If OP wants the entire JSON; this code will not work.Then, OP may want many things ..

Answer (score 1):

Your `json.loads` was failing because of the final semicolon. It will work if you use a regex to extract only the object string (excluding the final semicolon).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
import requests 
import re
import json



page = requests.get("https://www.gofundme.com/f/eric-stevens-care-trust")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
txt = all_scripts[0].get_text()
data = json.loads(re.findall(r'window\.initialState = ({.*?});', txt)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine for now, I might try to write a pure lxml version or at least improve the searching for the element.

This solution uses regex to get only the JSON data, without the `window.initialState =` and semicolon.

```py
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_1 = "https://www.gofundme.com/f/eric-stevens-care-trust"

req = requests.get(url_1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')

script_tag = soup.find('script')

raw_json = re.fullmatch(r"window\.initialState = (.+);", script_tag.text).group(1)

json_content = json.loads(raw_json)
```