# How to scrape and save charts from website when the data points are dynamic in the html

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, charts

Is there a way to scrape the data from this chart using python libraries like bs4 or requests?

I tried to look at the website source data but I don't see the data points anywhere in the HTML.

I saw one variable that changes as I move my mouse around the chart but I have no idea how that works.

https://infogram.com/world-container-index-1h17493095xl4zj

Any ideas on how I can download and save these datapoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to extract the `script` text that populates the Chart and converted it to `json` format

`final_data` has the data in `json` format. I think you could now extract whatever you need.

Here is the Code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = "https://infogram.com/world-container-index-1h17493095xl4zj"
resp = requests.get(url)
html = resp.text


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

s = soup.findAll('script')
main_script = None

for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i].contents:
        if 'window.infographicData' in s[i].contents[0]:
            main_script = s[i].contents[0]
            break


main_script = main_script.lstrip('window.infographicData=')
main_script = main_script.rstrip(';')

final_data = json.loads(main_script)
```

Comment: how would you extract the data from this though, the formatting looks so strange

Comment: can i ask how you found the script and window.inforaphicData?

Comment: if you look here https://en.macromicro.me/charts/947/commodity-ccfi-scfi i cant find the similar information to extract this

Comment: @anarchy Everysite is different. You have to look whether your data is present in HTML code itself (or) being populated by Javascript (or) comes from an API. For example this site: https://en.macromicro.me/charts/947/commodity-ccfi-scfi gets the data from an API.

Comment: is there a way to extract that?

Comment: Yes. You can directly make a GET request to the API using ```requests``` module and extract the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68094929/how-to-extract-a-chart-that-gets-it-data-from-an-api-using-python i posted another question if you want to check it out for this

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the data in the script balise at the end : line 3794.

Comment: sorry i dont understand, which part is that?

Comment: All the data are at the end of the source, you must search : window.infographicData={
So you should write something like : if '{"infographicData"' in script.text:

Look at this question, there is an example how to extract data : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030726/extracting-data-from-script-tag-using-beautifulsoup-in-python