# how to extract a chart that gets it data from an API using python

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am trying to get the data from this website, https://en.macromicro.me/charts/947/commodity-ccfi-scfi ,

I understand that the data is called from an API, how do I find out how the call is made and how do I extract it using python?

I am new to python and html in general so I have no idea where to start.

I tried,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
urlheader = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Authorization": "Bearer 640eabc473294fbac27930ef08d28ab4",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cookie": "PHPSESSID=5q99iuiarvf1ba2lafh6je5hr5; _ga=GA1.2.628840989.1624431403; _gid=GA1.2.146418174.1624431403; _fbp=fb.1.1624431403269.1337227854; _hjTLDTest=1; _hjid=89fd1c1b-93a7-4da9-bf90-46efcb6aae15; _hjFirstSeen=1",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Host": "en.macromicro.me",
    "Referer": "https://en.macromicro.me/charts/947/commodity-ccfi-scfi",
}

url = "https://en.macromicro.me/charts/data/947"



req = requests.post(url,headers=urlheader)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

But I get the following error

```
<html><body><p>{"status":"Method Not Allowed","code":405,"text":"HTTP 405 (POST \/charts\/data\/947)","level":0}</p></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `GET` request to the API using `requests` and convert the response to `json`.

`resp` has the data in `json` format and you can easily extract the info that you need.

```
import requests

url = "https://en.macromicro.me/charts/data/947"

resp = requests.get(url)
resp = resp.json()
```

Comment: hey it doesnt work, i get an error, i updated my question

Comment: your code gives this error `{'status': 'Method Not Allowed', 'code': 405, 'text': 'HTTP 405 (POST /charts/data/947)', 'level': 0}`

Comment: Why are you making a ```POST``` request ? My code and your code are completely different. How would you expect it to work ?

Comment: hey @Ram I dont get it, sometimes i get this `{'success': 0, 'data': [], 'msg': 'error #244'}` sometimes it works, sometimes i get `<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>`

Comment: is the website blocking me?